# difficulty with redisplaying other img on the same jlabel

Tags: java, swing

I am a bit of stuck. When I press the button submit is should redisplay another picture on the same position the JLabel images so if anyone have any ideas i would appreciate them I am using eclipse and the program is compiling and running. Here is the code

```
/** Here is the GUI of the program
 * class name SlideShowGui.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;   

public class SlideShowGui extends JPanel  implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel name, comments, images;
    JTextField namejtf, commentsjtf, captionjtf;
    JButton submit;
    ImageIcon pictures;


    SlideShowGui()
    {


        name = new JLabel("Name:");
        this.add(name);

        namejtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(namejtf);

        comments = new JLabel("Comments:");
        this.add(comments);

        commentsjtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(commentsjtf);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        this.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);


        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo1.jpg");
        images = new JLabel(pictures);
        this.add(images);


//      pictures2 = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
//      images2 = new JLabel(pictures2);
//      this.add(images2);



        captionjtf = new JTextField(24);
        this.add(captionjtf);

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
        if(ae.getSource() == submit)
        {

            pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
            images = new JLabel(pictures);

            System.out.println("test");
        }

    }
}

    }

/**The driver class of the program. Here is the JFrame 
 * class name TestSlideShow.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestSlideShow 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        SlideShowGui panel = new SlideShowGui();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(300,600);
        application.setLocation(400,100);
        application.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this

```
if(ae.getSource() == submit)
    {

        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
        images = new JLabel(pictures);

        System.out.println("test");
    }
```

to

```
if(ae.getSource() == submit)
    {

        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
        images.setIcon(pictures);

        System.out.println("test");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

in some of cases Icon/ImageIcon doesn't works (sucked from web or HDD)

```
pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
pictures.getImage().flush();
images.setIcon(pictures);
```

Comment: I didn't knew that thingy :-) Moreover OP missed his Event Dispatcher Thread too.

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali glad to help you, not sure in this case, EDT could be invoked from ActionListener correctly, I think that in this case is accepted answer correct for ...

Comment: Too true, no doubt, since he wants the image of the same Label to be swapped with something new.

Answer (score 3):

as far as I can tell, you're not adding the new image in your listener. I also think you need to call repaint, in order for the new image to be displayed:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       if(ae.getSource() == submit){
        pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
        images = new JLabel(pictures);
        this.add(images); //adding the new image to your JPanel
        repaint(); //repaint in order to show the image
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Try this and it should work

Comment: And you're sure you're calling repaint()? If not you need to minimize and maximize the window for it to show.

Comment: You have to `revalidate()` too before `repaint()` for changes to take effect. +1 though for `repaint()`.