# ImagePath with %20 is not working

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I have the following code:

```
labelShowImagenApp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(rutaAbs.toURI().toURL()));
```

where `rutaAbs` is a path to an image file.
The problem is that when that path contains spaces (like "im a png.png") it doesn't work, the label remains empty.

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

**edit:** I have noticed that if a folder that contains the image has spaces, it will not work either.

Comment: Is the URL correctly encoded?

Comment: can you not use URI and URL encoders in Java?

Comment: If I don't get the URL of that file, it doesn't work (dunno why).

Comment: are you sure that you are not Using URI?

Comment: I'm using URL as you can see :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it doing this:

```
            if (rutaAbs.toString().contains("%20")){
                String replacedPath = (rutaAbs.toString().replace("%20", " "));
                rutaAbs = new File(replacedPath);
            }
```

Thanks a lot everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

For a File use:

```
labelShowImagenApp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(rutaAbs.getPath()));
```

*(For other readers.)*
For a resource in the application (possibly inside a jar) use

```
labelShowImagenApp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/...")));
```

---

***Corrected Answer:***

This is how I in general do it:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(rutaAbs);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
icon.getImage().flush();  // @mKorbel
labelShowImagenApp.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: Not working, I need to pass an URL, without that it won't work. (File must have "file://" before the absolute path)

Comment: The [javadoc on ImageIcon(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String)) then would give a wrong example. But it explains why I am doing it for years like above.

Comment: Not working either, the first time it is set it works, but I have a method that every time I click in a row of a table, the icon is changed taking a path that is contained in that row, and it doesn't change. (1st time i set the icon: http://imgur.com/rDphUxe ; 2nd time when I click a row: http://imgur.com/bbsLbJj ).

Comment: Use`EventQueue.invokeLater` and/or `repaint(50L)`.

Comment: @Joop Eggen not EventQueue.invokeLater and/or repaint(50L) but [flush() for ImageIcon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9616521/714968) :-) +1 previously

Comment: Sorry, I forgot saying that fileAbs is actually a file:
`File rutaAbs = new File((String) webModel.getValueAt(tablaWeb.getSelectedRow(), 2));

                rutaAbs = rutaAbs.getAbsoluteFile();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
labelShowImagenApp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(URLDecoder.decode(rutaAbs.toURI().toURL(), "UTF-8")));
```

**edited.**

Comment: Hi, class URL doesn't have any getBytes() method :/

Comment: Ah my bad , sorry , I thought you pass string , I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have tried `labelShowImagenApp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(URLDecoder.decode(rutaAbs.toURI().toURL().toString(), "UTF-8")));` because the code you write doesn't work (decode method receives a String not a URL) and it's still not working ><