# How to update an ImageIcon in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

```
import javax.swing.*;
{

JFrame ShoppingMarket=new JFrame();
{
  ShoppingMarket.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin   \\Desktop\\The Da Vinci Code.jpg")));
  ShoppingMarket.pack();
  ShoppingMarket.setVisible(true);  
}
ShoppingMarket.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin   \\Desktop\\Angels And Demons.jpg")));
ShoppingMarket.pack();
ShoppingMarket.setVisible(true);    
}
```

It doesn't  clear the screen on closing the first window. so both pictures are shown on screen.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of adding a new `JLabel` to the frame, store the original to a field of the enclosing class. Then you can simply call `label.setIcon(theNewIcon)`, where I'm assuming the field is named `label`. See the relevant [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29).

Comment: [ImageIcon.getImage().flush();](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9616521/714968) should be important for resources disposed loosely on HDD